# Encode pattern layout in apache log4j

Tags: java, apache, log4j

Trying to use the following pattern layout to print encoded log messages, so that \n will not be printed as a new line in the logs.

```
  <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
     <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss,SSS} %5p [%t] (%F:%L) - %enc{%m}%n"/>
  </layout>
```

But it literally prints `%enc{` before every message and prints `}` at the end of the messages, instead of encoding them. \n is also not being replaced.

Example: For this code `logger.info("my \n message")` following is the output log

```
08-01-2018 01:26:37,642  INFO [localhost-startStop-1] (ClassName1.java:53) - %enc{my 
message}
```

instead it should be like,

```
08-01-2018 01:26:37,642  INFO [localhost-startStop-1] (ClassName1.java:53) - my message
```

Followed this document https://logging.apache.org/log4j/log4j-2.1/manual/layouts.html But I'm not sure what is wrong with the pattern.

Answer (score 1):

You should determine the encoding format in curly brackets. For example `%enc{%m}{HTML}` encodes the message in HTML format. You could also use CRLF: `enc{%m}{CRLF}`

Comment: still prints like %enc{ ... }{CRLF} without actually encoding. The layout xml tag mentioned in the question is under <appender class="org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender">. Is that is ok right? All other elements from the patterns like date formatting works fine except this encoding.

Comment: The DailyRollingFileAppender just puts a timestamp as a prefix to the log but maybe the default configuration of it may overlap with what you are trying to do. If that is the case you may need to implement your custom appender, that's pain. Use the `layout` parameter of DailyRollingFileAppender to determine the pattern layout.

Comment: Just to mention, the DRFA also keeps seperate files for each day of logging.

Comment: Try, <PatternLayout>
        <Pattern>%d{MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss,SSS} %5p [%t] (%F:%L) - %enc{%m}{CRLF}</Pattern>
      </PatternLayout>

Comment: Also try removing the dash before %enc